# Gpg4win installation error

Tags: microsoft-outlook, gnupg, gpg4win, kleopatra

I'm having a problem with gpg4win. I (stupidly) experimented with the S/MIME encryption button in Outlook and even when I unchecked it, it caused GPG to hang while trying to "resolve signatures".

So, I have uninstalled gpg4win (which in itself was a major b4llache), and I now want to reinstall it.

However, when I do, Kleopatra fails its self-test with the following output:

[image]

So I run the command `gpgconf --check-options gpg`
and I get the output:

```
gpg:OpenPGP:C%3a\Program Files (x86)\Gpg4win\..\GnuPG\bin\gpg.exe:1:1:
```

I assume that one of the 1s indicates that it has exited with an error, but other than that, I'm clueless.

Can you help me get this back, please?

If I just click the continue button, Kleopatra crashes out.

Comment: According to my search about your issue, there might be some file folders or registry keys will still remain in your computer. Guess if these remained file would influence the new installation? Just a possible direction for you to troubleshoot. https://www.gpg4win.org/doc/en/gpg4win-compendium_37.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Jeff](https://superuser.com/users/1174833/jeff-yang7) answered this question - The link he provided in the comment above showed me some other areas where stuff was hiding and not being uninstalled.
I *thought* I had followed these instructions, but I ran through them again and uninstalled everything, and then the re-install worked (somewhat frustratingly because I thought I'd followed them previously).

Thanks Jeff.